# Using preposition "on " with the words(forbid/forbidden)

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

In the following contexts, and regarding the words (forbid/forbidden) I get confused alot.Actually I looked the words up in the dictionary and I couldn't find any thing about using these words with the preposition "on". So are the the following sentences applicable using "on" or should I stick with "for".

1- I forbid smoking on/for you.

2- Smoking is forbidden on/for me.

3- It is forbidden on/for you to smoke here.

Note : I know there are different forms to make sentences using these words, but I'm just interested in the mentioned context above.

Answer (score 1):

The first two uses of *on* are grammatical, but very strange. They also don't mean what you think they mean:

1. I forbid smoking on you.
   → I forbid anybody from smoking on top of you.
2. Smoking is forbidden on you.
   → Nobody is allowed to smoke on top of you.

The third sentence is simply ungrammatical when used with *on*.

---

More natural phrasing for each of the sentences is as follows:

1. I forbid you to smoke.
2. I am forbidden to smoke.
3. You are forbidden to smoke here.

Note the change in construction and the use of the single preposition *to*.